# Asp.Net WebAPI Wait the Current Response Sent before Next Request Executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, queue

I have a webApi that gets requests and execute the data with XPO. According to my business logic, to avoid conflicts on same DB table, every request must be executed one by one in a order.

Honestly, i couldn't try anything yet. I'm a little bit confused with asynchronous side of Asp.Net WebAPI.

The code below is the part of the response is being created in a Custom DelegatingHandler. When the `base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)` method executed, my business logic starts in related `System.Web.Http.ApiController` class.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
// some logic on request like isUserGranted etc.
//
//
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
return buildApiResponse(request, response);
}
```

Probably, I have a misconception here. I need to wait until current response has completed to handle the next Request if there is a request on queue. I've read about ConcurrentQueue but couldn't realise how to implement it for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to my business logic, to avoid conflicts on same DB table, every request must be executed one by one in a order.

This is "pessimistic locking", and is generally considered not good for scalability reasons. If possible, change the business requirements to use "optimistic locking".

But if you really want to use pessimistic locking, you can enforce one-at-a-time behavior using an asynchronous lock (`SemaphoreSlim`):

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // some logic on request like isUserGranted etc.

  await Mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    return buildApiResponse(request, response);
  }
  finally
  {
    Mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking to understand.
Every request creates a instance of my DelegatingHandler and this static SemaphoreSlim object will wait if there is another execution on these lines, am i Right? So, if it is, is it in the order?

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim` will make them run one at a time. The order is roughly FIFO but not guaranteed.

Comment: Your suggestion caused me to do a further search, so thank you. But then why i shouldn't use a lock object with lock keyword?

Comment: @Gogo-the-Cat: Because code cannot `await` while holding a `lock`.

Comment: It looks like  `SemaphoreSlim` is doing its job for my case. And it is not FIFO guaranteed, it is not the same order as they requested. Thank you for your sharing. I'll mark this answer as solution.